# Setting Radio Group Checked Status

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm building a component for a group of radio buttons that sets a class on the checked radio component.

```
export default function RadioBlockGroup({
  options,
  radioName,
  isChecked
}){
const [radioIsChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(isChecked);
  return(
    {options.map((option, i) => {

      return (
        <Radio
          key={i}
          radioID={option.radioID}
          radioName={radioName}
          radioLabel={option.radioLabel}
          radioClass={`${(radioIsChecked === option.radioID) ? "active" : ""} `}
          onChange={() => setIsChecked(option.radioID)}
          isChecked={option.isChecked}
          />
      )
    })}
  );
}
```

This works great, **unless** I set one of the radio buttons to be "checked" - doing so breaks the ability to click and change the selected radio button.

```
radioName: "radio-blocks",
options: [
  {
    radioID: "1",
    radioLabel: "One",
  },
  {
    radioID: "2",
    radioLabel: "Two",
    isChecked: true,
  }
]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: you are hard-coding the `isChecked` attribute so that no matter what button you click the `option` with `isChecked` property set to `true` will always be the one selected. So try doing this

```
export default function RadioBlockGroup({
  options,
  radioName,
  isChecked
}){
const [radioIsChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(isChecked);
  return(
    {options.map((option, i) => {

      return (
        <Radio
          key={i}
          radioID={option.radioID}
          radioName={radioName}
          radioLabel={option.radioLabel}
          radioClass={`${(radioIsChecked === option.radioID) ? "active" : ""} `}
          onChange={() => setIsChecked(option.radioID)}
          isChecked={radioIsChecked === option.radioID}
          />
      )
    })}
  );
}
```

Comment: That does allow clicking other radio buttons, but it doesn't initially set the checked radio. Am I doing that part wrong? I'm sure there will be a need to have a radio set to `checked` on the initial page load.

Comment: on initial page load, the radio button will be selected whose id you  passed as `isChecked` prop